# Insert/Upsert to a Meteor Collection with Unacknowldeged Write Concern

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In Meteor, how do you Insert/Upsert to a Meteor Collection with Unacknowldeged Write Concern `w=0`?

Can the write concern be set during the insert/upsert, rather than as a environment variable?

Comment: Why is this down voted? Are you performing your inserts that you don't want this on the server side?

Comment: @Akshat I'm performing the inserts on the server side

Comment: Ah, ok cool are you ok with altering core meteor packages? I'm not sure if its possible per update, but you can alter `mongo_driver.js` to expose this so it can be an option (is safe=true) the same thing?

Comment: @Akshat I will try modifying the core package. Where can I find the file to modify? (I'm on Mac OSX)

Comment: Why do you want have write concern off? I ask because most people want write concern off so their server doesnt block while waiting for a response/result. Meteor does not block on writes unless provided a callback.

Comment: to help users coming from google: you can specify an application wide write concern within the MONGO_URL params. ex: `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27001,localhost:27002,localhost:27003/dbName?replicaSet=meteor&readPreference=primaryPreferred&w=majority`   See: http://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-replica-sets-with-meteor.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass writeConcern as of Mongo v2.6:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert

No, you can't pass that option in Meteor.  It's not documented here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#update

I did some digging to see what you'd have to do if you wanted to patch Meteor.  Here is the link to their update/insert/upsert code:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/collection.js

It looks like it delegates to DDP which is their Distributed Data Persistence framework.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Can't you use RawCollection API[http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Mongo-Collection-rawCollection] for that?